# For count from 2

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

Let assume that I have simple code.

```
list = [1,3,4,5,6,7,8]

for i, val in enumerate(list):
        print(val)
```

I would like to start from `i=2`. How do this in the simplest way?

Something like `for(int i=2; i<list.lenght; i++)` in `java`.

Comment: One more good advice: don't use `list` as variable name, since it is a built-in type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use a normal loop over the index:

```
lst = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
for i in range(2, len(lst)):
    val = lst[i]
    print(val)
```

Or you skip the first elements:

```
lst = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
for i, val in enumerate(lst):
    if i < 2:
        continue
    print(val)
```

A third option would be to use [itertools.islice](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to skip the first element. This would allow you to keep the indexes as 0, 1, … although you skipped an element:

```
for i, val in enumerate(itertools.islice(lst, 2, None)):
    print(i, val) # would begin with 1 3, then 2 4, …
```

As your iterable is a list, you can use list indexing for this as well:

```
for i, val in enumerate(lst[2:]):
    print(i, val)
```

Comment: For the second way couldn't you do something like: `lst[2:]`?

Comment: @squiguy For the second? Not if you want the original indexes to work.

Comment: That's true. I just thought since the poster wanted to *start* from there, you could do that.

Comment: If your Python is not too old you can pass a starting index to `enumerate` as a second argument, making the `islice` method the winner (to me anyway).

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: for i,val in enumerate(list[2:]):
            print(val)
   .... 
4
5
6
7
8
```